# Refreshing Power BI Data within Dataset using ServicePrinicipal connection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I wanted t ask this question as I am not finding answers anywhere online.

I have a Power BI Dataset that gets data from a Kusto Cluster using my credentials. Can i change the data fetching part to a **Service Principal** Or an **System-Assigned** Or **User-Assigned Managed Identity** Or something else? I would like to remove dependency on human accounts for my Dataset refresh. Is this something possible today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today no data sources in the Power BI service support storing Service Principal credentials or connecting with a managed identity.